# How to compute center of gravity of trapezoid

Tags: geometry

Hot to compute the mediana / center of gravity of trapezoid in analytical geometry?

[image]

Greetings from Poland!

Comment: 30;1? Is the 1 correct?

Comment: Quoting wiki's entry of  [centroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_a_polygon) of a polygon,
$$
\begin{align}
C_x &= \frac{1}{6A} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(x_i + x_{i+1})(x_i y_{i+1} - x_{i+1}y_i)\\
C_y &= \frac{1}{6A} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(y_i + y_{i+1})(x_i y_{i+1} - x_{i+1}y_i)
\end{align}
$$
where $A = \frac12\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}(x_i y_{i+1} - x_{i+1}y_i)$ is polygon's signed area.

Comment: There three centers of gravity 1) area based as you stated  2) side based same linear density  3) vertices equally weighted ; Ok?.

Comment: Do you want to establish the formula or just to get the value ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: break the shape into two parts and take moments about a point. I am happy to provide a full solution if you still need help.